# Error while loading .so file in android project from tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, gradle

I wanted to add tensorflow support to my android project (my own version of object detection from the demo)and didn't want to deal with `bazel` or `cmake` to build the native libraries that tensorflow uses. So as recommended through many issues posted at the tensorflow GitHub project I downloaded the latest successful nightly build from Jenkins that contains an apk file to test the object detection demo and .jar file along with the .so files from different architectures.

So I added the prebuilt libraries `libtensorflow_demo.so` and `libtensorflow_inference.so` **(arm64-v8a ,armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64)** and the `libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar` file to my libs directory.

I added these lines to my gradle :

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

in my proguard-rules-pro I added this :

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

to load the **.so** library I'm using :

```
 System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_demo");
```

I unzipped the **.apk** to check if it's there and it was there.

from my logcat I spotted this :

```
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 123ms, TensorFlow version: 1.8.0-rc1
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/frozen_inference_graph_stripped.pb'
```

But as the app as it starts it crashes and throw this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.tracking.ObjectTracker.initNative(int, int, boolean) (tried Java_com_example_aboussaada_myapplication_tracking_ObjectTracker_initNative and Java_com_example_aboussaada_myapplication_tracking_ObjectTracker_initNative__IIZ)
    at com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.tracking.ObjectTracker.initNative(Native Method)
    at com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.tracking.ObjectTracker.init(ObjectTracker.java:261)
    at com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.tracking.ObjectTracker.getInstance(ObjectTracker.java:224)
    at com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.tracking.MultiBoxTracker.onFrame(MultiBoxTracker.java:219)
    at com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.DetectorActivity.processImage(DetectorActivity.java:215)
    at com.example.aboussaada.myapplication.camera.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:155)
    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1153)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

So what I'm doing wrong here ?? any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, downloading and including the `.so` file to your own project was not enough. Since we're including a pre-compiled version of the library the native methods (in the `.cpp` files) have the package name of the tensorflow demo on their names. That's why this error occur since our own projects packages named differently.

- To solve this problem you need to rename your package to `org.tensorflow.demo` and make sure that `ObjectTracker.java` is under `org.tensorflow.demo.tracking`.
- Second solution would be  changing the naming of the native methods
  in the `.cpp` files according to your package name and then rebuild
  the `.so` file with bazel (faced many problems there if anyone manage
  to do it please mention how).
- I hope the tensorflow team will mention this information when suggesting to download and drop the pre-buit version so the not so experienced developers won't waste unnecessary time on this issue.